# On macOS 10.15.3, App Store crashes upon clicking the account icon

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, catalina, crash

When my system was 10.15.2, the App Store's functions worked well. However, after I upgraded to 10.15.3

1. Open App Store
2. Click my account icon
3. App Store crashed and show error message

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try to signout and sign in back your Apple ID from System Preference first ? and can try to see if App Store crash again ?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to paste the text of the crash instead of posting a picture?

Comment: thanks all, i found issue is from antivirus application, upgraded to new version, issue resolved